# Count always same code across a data.frame of variables

Tags: r, frequency

I would like to count the frequency of occurrence of the same code, say '9' across a vector variables in a `data.frame`. For example, take:

```
dat<-data.frame(matrix(sample(1:10,50,T),ncol=5))
```

How often does 9 occur? Of course I could `table` each column, but I would like to have a vector of length 5 with frequency counts of 9. Would be thankful for advice on how to get there.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `colSums`:

```
set.seed(1)
dat<-data.frame(matrix(sample(1:10,50,T),ncol=5))

colSums(dat == 9)
#X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 
# 1  0  1  1  1
```